# Chrome bug with css transform on div with fixed background

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've discovered an interesting bug (?). The key thing is that if you set transform:rotateX() to a div with fixed background, then the background is behaving different in each browser.

See this example: http://codepen.io/thes01/pen/EZXpBY

```css
.foo{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateX(20deg);
}

.bar{
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.drodd.com/images15/nature13.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div
```

In Chrome and Opera, there is a parallax effect on the images, in Edge, the fixed attribute doesn't apply and IE behaves as I would expect - the transform property doesn't affect the fixed background. I did not try Firefox.

Also, if you apply the transform effect on bar instead of foo, then it is a bit laggy in Chrome.

Note that other transforms are notable as well - e.g. scale() and skewX() do similar effect, rotateZ() shifts the image horizontally when scrolling (quite a nice effect here: https://www.jardasvoboda.cz/ (not my site)) or vertically reversed at 180deg angle and skewY() does nothing strange.

What do you think? Is this a bug? Which browser is "correct"?

Comment: You made this error: width: 100; should be width: 100px;, or something else....

Comment: this is not the thing - see http://codepen.io/thes01/pen/PWjBam